# ng-show and ng-hide don't work for a fraction of a second

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my app I have two div attributes which I want to appear depending on the state (state1 or state2). The first div1 contains a button, for which when clicked transitions to state2 (div1 dissapears, div2 appears).

```
 <div id="state1" ng-show="firstMode"><button ng-click="goTo2()">Go</button></div>
 <div id="state2" ng-hide="firstMode"><button ng-click="goTo2()">Go</button></div>
```

// controller logic

```
$scope.firstMode = true
$scope.goTo2 = function() {
     $scope.firstMode = false
}
```

When viewing it on mobile both divs are shown for a fraction of a second before the actual state kicks in. Same happens when clicking on the button to transition to state2. Basically the following happens when the view is loaded:

div1 and div2 shown

div1 shown, div2 hidden

click on button (to show div2, hide div1)

div1 and div2 shown

div2 shown, div1 hidden

How can I prevent this messy transition and loading of the view?

Comment: for the initial flicker from loading the page, you should look into [ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) 
and if it gives you problems, look into [ngCloak issue and its fix](http://briantree.se/quick-tip-15-fix-ng-cloak-flicker-angularjs/)

Comment: Great, will try tomorrow. Any idea whether it will also solve the second issue?

Comment: Ng-cloak does not work for me. Ng-switch on the other hand does...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description of the problem, you probably have ngAnimate loaded and you style sheet has some default css transitions.  To verify, try adding:

```
app.run(function($animate){
    $animate.enabled(false);
})
```

to your run function.  This will globally disable animations.  If the problem disappears, you can remove and start trying to figure out where your "rogue" css transitions are.